# How to ask StackExchange for more results exceeding 30?

Tags: stackexchange-api, stackexchange

I'm using the [Usage of /questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=100&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) URI request to fetch a list of questions from stackoverflow.

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow
```

This works, however it only returns 30 results. How do I specify to the API to give me other results like 10 or 100?

I'm looking for a property like '`maxResults`' but found none. Help anyone?

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging

Comment: Hey thanks, it works. You can place that as answer if you want. : ) I'm very new to Stackexchange API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the page you linked to, that “play with it” toolbox offers a parameter called `pagesize`, so first guess would be that that might be relevant (in combination with `page`.)

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging says you can not specify a pagesize larger than 100, but explains how those two parameters can be used to “paginate” through larger result sets.

There is also a `has_more` property that will tell you upfront whether it makes sense to request a “next page” from your current position.